# PHP - if page is index.php redirect to index.php?page=something

Tags: php

Is it possible to redirect `index.php` to `index.php?page=something`? Every attempt I've made so far causes a redirect loop.

Comment: show us the attempt(s) you tried. And yes, it is possible. Make sure you've no mod rewrites neither in htaccess.

Comment: You've an answer below now; see that. If that still doesn't work, then you will need to elaborate on your question and add your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this:

**index.php**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET["page"])){
    header("Location: index.php?page=something");
    exit;
}
?>
```